# Link uploaded files on a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-upload, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a simple file server, where you can upload files and these files go to a db and a upload folder. Now, it only needs a list of linked files.

Right now I have this:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```

The uploaded file shows right after uploaded. That is why I need those links.

Comment: Can you clarify what is it that you are asking? What have you tried, and which result are you getting instead?

Comment: I've been able to upload files using Flask, I have an uploads folder. Using the send_from_directory method, I can only see the file right after it is uploaded, so I need to create a list with links, each link should be a uploaded file; Like Dropbox.

Comment: So you only need to list all files in the upload directory?

Comment: Yeah, each one a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, abspath, dirname

@app.route('/files')
def files():
    files = [f for f in listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']) if isfile(join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f))]
    return render_template("files.html", files=files)
```

**files.html**

```
{% for file in files %}

    <a href="{{ url_for('uploaded_file', filename = file) }}">{{ file }}</a> <br />

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey Matt, thank you. That'll do it for now. (Just for curiosity) I have a database on mysql, with urls from each file is uploaded. Just as you explain above, it is possible to change 'upload_file' for a SELECT and get the file location?